# binary files writing problems

Tags: c, binary, linked-list

Ok here's the edited version of my code along with the function that creates the list. start is initialized as a global variable and start=NULL. I also changed my fwrite. Rather than enumerate a long list of variables i used buf to get its contents(i.e name, title,type...). mygets is just a function i created to remove the \n that comes after. Same problem arises. Foreign symbols come out.

```
void saving()
    {
            FILE *out;
            struct node buf;
            struct node *current;

            out = fopen("foo", "wb");
            if(out == NULL) return;

            printf("Writing to file...");

            while(current != NULL)
            {

                   fwrite(&buf, sizeof(struct node), 1, out);
            }

            printf("Done!\n");
            fclose(out);
    }



void create()
{
node *p,*q;
int item;
char ti[STRLEN],na[STRLEN],ty[6];

printf("Warrior name: ");
mygets(na);

printf("\nWarrior title: ");
mygets(ti);

printf("\nWarrior Type and Class Encoding: ");
fgets(ty,6,stdin);

p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

strcpy(p->name,na);
strcpy(p->title,ti);
strcpy(p->type,ty);

p->next=NULL;
if(start==NULL)
{
start=p;
}
else
{
q=start;
while(q->next!=NULL)
{
q=q->next;
}
q->next=p;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you assigning the struct node *current to anything? It'll be pointing to random memory or be null (as it seems to be in your case).

Comment: @Baldrick I edited my code and added struct node *start = NULL. I let current = start which gave me an output but only the first line is written and the rest is garbage.

Comment: Take a look at the answer by 0xF1 comment below - he explains in more detail what I mean. I still can't see which list you are working with. Where is the head of the actual list you are writing out?

Answer (score 2):

As [Baldrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609288/baldrick) pointed out in his comment, you have not assigned `current` to the start/head node of the linked list.

The way you are doing, **dereferencing a non-initialized pointer**, can lead to your program crash, fortunately its not so for you.

Use:

```
struct node *current = head;    // Or whatever is your head node name
```

By the way, if you writing a binary file, its better not to name it **foo.txt**, use binary extensions like *.bin*, *.dat*, etc. or better don't use any extension.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. But the program will only write the first line then garbage

Comment: @user2714453 : For that check your Linked List implementation, whether you have assigned the `next` of the last node as `NULL`.

Comment: @user2714453 : Are you sure that your `mygets()` function is working fine, because I think it is not saving input from user to corresponding strings. Try using `scanf("%s", ...);`.

Comment: yes, its working fine, the code for that function is not included but i have been using it for sometime now so there's no problem to it

Comment: @user2714453 : Did you try `scanf`?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop variable is unintialized. So probably there is nothing written, because it might be NULL at the time. You must initialize it to a proper value so it can enter the while loop. Using a debugger would have shown you this immediately.

Depending on your definition of node, the calls to `fwrite` could also yield wrong results, but you should post it, before one can say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For saving a linked list into a file successfully one must start from **first node**(Head Node) and keep moving to further nodes until last node.
in your code you did not initialise the *current to the Head node.

you should take the address of **Head Node** as parameter to the **saving()** function. so that can be used to initialise the current.

while calling the **saving()** function you may pass the **Head Node**

```
void main()
{   
    //other code...

    saving(Head); //while calling the saving() method just pass the head node as parameter

   //remaining code... 
}
```

so that the *current would be initialised to **Head Node**(first node)

void saving(struct node *current)
    {
            FILE *out;

```
       out = fopen("foo.txt", "wb");
        if(out == NULL) return;

        printf("Writing to file...");

        while(current != NULL)
        {
                    fwrite (current->name, sizeof current->name, 1, out);
                fwrite (current->title, sizeof current->title, 1, out);
                fwrite (current->type, sizeof current->type, 1, out);
                current = current->next;
        }

        printf("Done!\n");
        fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: What would be by my calling function in main? All my functions are void. Im just a bit confused how i can call the head in this function

Comment: whenever you call the saving() function just pass the head node to it